# Peewee syntax for selecting on null field

Tags: python, mysql, null, isnull, peewee

I have researched this everywhere and can't seem to find an answer.  I hope I haven't duplicated this (as it's my first question on SO).

I am trying to write a select query with Peewee that would normally go ... WHERE foo = NULL; in SQL world.

MySQL looks like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| id        | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| user      | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| peer      | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| deleted   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
| confirmed | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My select query looks like this:

```
Peers.select().where(Peers.user == 'foo' and Peers.deleted is None)
```

But it doesn't work!  I've tried `Peers.deleted == ""` and `Peers.deleted == "NULL"`.  The MySQL syntax should end in `WHERE deleted is NULL;` but nothing in Peewee seems to be doing that.

Can anyone help?  What am I missing from the docs?

Updated from Foo Bar User's comment:
`and not Peers.deleted` didn't work, but it led me to more information.  It seems that peewee wants the `where` clauses chained together.  So instead of

`Peers.select().where(Peers.user == 'foo' and Peers.deleted is None)`

it should be:

`Peers.select().where(Peers.user == 'foo').where(Peers.deleted is None)`

Sadly, that still doesn't yield the right syntax to select on null rows in deleted.

Comment: maybe `and not Peers.deleted`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First off you must use the bitwise operands for "and" and "or".  Then for is null, use `>>`:

```
Peers.select().where((Peers.user == 'foo') & Peers.deleted.is_null())
```

For not null you would negate it:

```
Peers.select().where(Peers.deleted.is_null(False))
```

It is documented: https://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html#query-operators

Comment: Is there an alternative to  `>> None`? It's not intuitive at all and as I don't use peewee every day I have to look it up every time :-(

Comment: Yes, two ways. If you do `.where(Foo.something == None)` Peewee will turn it into "IS NULL". Alternatively, you can do `.where(Foo.something.is_null(True))`. Similarly, `.where(Foo.something.is_null(False))` will produce `WHERE foo.something IS NOT NULL`.